# Folding/Collapsing functions and subroutines in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6, ide

Do you know if there's a way to fold/collapse functions and subroutines (and better yet: ifs and whiles) in the Visual Basic 6 IDE? At least with a plugin or something similar?

I have to deal with files of thousands of lines sometimes and with no cropping it's just impossible (It's a very old app off course).

Please note that it's not Vb.Net, it's VB6.0

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "with no cropping"?

Comment: Visual Basic is also "just text"; can't you just copy and paste them into a proper IDE?

Comment: I guess "folding" or "collapsing" is the common term for what you are searching.

Comment: The VB6 IDE has an option to only show one function at a time. It can also show an entire file with optional function separator lines. It's under Tools->Options (don't remember the actual option and don't have VB6 installed on this machine).

Comment: @xxbbcc By cropping I mean making a block of code to be reduced to one line visually, isn't that the right word? I'm not a native english speaker so please correct me if I'm wrong.
I just checked the option, it's not exactly what I'm looking for but it may help, thanks.

Comment: Also: Refactor instead of just hiding the ugly. See [The Problem With Code Folding](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I can and that's what I've been doing, however working at vb6 has it's advantages (Intellisense, Jumping to function definition, getting function/sub callers,... )

Comment: @steven2308: no, it hasn't. The modern free versions of visual studio can do all that, and better.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I use those options every day, but it may be thanks to a plugin I have, I'm not sure. Does Visual studio actually support vb6 proyects? I think it only works from Vb.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in Visual Basic 6 IDE is no fold/collapse functions. What to do instead?

- Use *Ctrl + Arrow Up* or *Ctrl + Arrow Dn* for skipping between functions
- Use the list of functions in the upper right corner instead of scrolling
- Toggle *Procedure View / Full Module View* by two buttons in the bottom left corner
- Must-to-have: install [Scroll Wheel Fix for VB6](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/837910/mouse-wheel-events-do-not-work-in-the-visual-basic-6.0-ide) and scroll source with mouse wheel (nirvana!)

Comment: No new information for me, I was hoping for something to really improve the 'experience' but since apparently there is nothing else to do and this may help other people I'll accept this one. Thanks Roman.

Comment: The link to install scroll wheel for VB6 is dead