# Is it possible to collapse code in the VB6 IDE?

Tags: vb6, ide, region

I'm looking for a way to collapse my VB6 code.
I found an option but I really hate it :

> Tools > Options > Editor Tab > uncheck "Default to Full Module View"

Is there a better way like the `#Region "regionName"` way used in the VB.NET IDE?

**EDIT :**

The two small buttons located in bottom left of the code window do the same as mentioned above
[image]

Comment: CodeSMART may work for you then. Have a look. I can't remember all the features. I would look at editing your question though to reflect what you're really after.

Comment: @Bugs, It's not free :/

Comment: @nbadaud no it's probably not. I've only used it briefly and it did have its advantages. I can't however remember if it collapsed regions of code. I don't remember if I ever did this myself. I think I stuck to module/procedure views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Folding/Collapsing functions and subroutines in Visual Basic 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550210/folding-collapsing-functions-and-subroutines-in-visual-basic-6)

Comment: @GSerg It does not solve the problem. I already know these tips

Comment: There have been no news on the subject @nbadaud. It's still a duplicate even if the answer is "no".

Answer (score 2):

No, isn't possible.
About CodeSMART:
may only show the 'branch lines'.
As for the regions, they are simply special comments, but nothing more.
See
http://www.axtools.com/products-codesmart-vb6.php